# Memcached process not getting killed

Tags: memcached

I have a memcache process running on my mac.Despite killing it with kill -9 pid.
When I do a ps -ef|grep memcached,it restarts the process with another pid. Dont know why this is happening.I have tried everything. 
Does anybody know the answer?

Thanks

Comment: It is probably running as part of another process, so when you kill it, it is just respawned with a new PID.

Comment: ok.So how can i kill it ... when i do ps -ef|grep memcache . i want it to return no memcache process running.